# Change div height when tab is selected

Tags: html, css

I have a tabbed content that has 4 tabs and in each there are going to be two divs that make up the border design. The problem that I'm running into is that I have no idea how to animate the divs to change height when the tab they're located in is selected. I have a [fiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/jw6tH/) and the markup is below.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1" id="welcome_selector">Welcome</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
</ul> 
<div class="tabcontentcontainer">
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current"> <div class="bordertop_animate"> </div>welcome tab will be empty, save for the borders <div class="borderbottom_animate"></div></div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"><div class="bordertop_animate"></div>        tab 2 content<div class="borderbottom_animate"></div>  </div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content"><div class="bordertop_animate"></div>        tab 3 content<div class="borderbottom_animate"></div>  </div>
<div id="tab-4" class="tab-content"><div class="bordertop_animate"></div>        tab 4 content<div class="borderbottom_animate"></div>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
width: 1000px;
min-height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.tabs {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
background: #000;
vertical-align: middle;
font-weight: 400;  
color:#FFF;
text-align: right;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 8px;
letter-spacing: 0.6px;
}

ul.tabs li {
background: #000;
vertical-align: middle;
font-weight: 400;  
color:#FFF;
text-align: right;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 8px;
letter-spacing: 0.6px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 55px 15px 55px 15px;
cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current {
background: #000;
color: #FFF;
}

#welcome_selector {
float: left;
padding-left: 128px;
 }

.tabcontentcontainer {
height: 400px;
width: 1000px;
background: url(http://placehold.it/1000x400) #000;
position: relative;
}

.tab-content {
display: none;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
display: inherit;
}

.bordertop_animate {
position: absolute;
height: 38px;
width: 966px;
border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
border-bottom: 0px solid #FFF;
border-left: 2px solid #FFF;
}

.borderbottom_animate {
position: absolute;
bottom: 15px;
height: 38px;
width: 966px;
border-top: 0px solid #FFF;
border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
border-left: 2px solid #FFF;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
})

})
```

I'd like for the first tab to keep current divs height which is 38px, however I'd like the other 3 tabs to have theirs at a height of 185px- but for the height to grow from 38px to 185px when the tab is selected. The animation would be similar to if the divs had a :hover css selector applied with a 0.5s transition, except it would happen when the tab is selected, not on mouseover.

Sorry if this isn't detailed or specific enough, this is my first time posting a question/and dealing with jquery.

Comment: Added css requested, and to be more clear- I want to the height effect on just the two divs **inside** the tabs [again, I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough /new] which would be the divs with the classes of 'bordertop_animate' and 'borderbottom_animate'

Comment: Please, to avoid more jQuery solutions can you clarify whether or not you want to use CSS3?

Comment: I would like the solution to be done in CSS3 if at all possible [I'll remove the jQuery tag asap]. The two divs ['bordertop_animate' and 'borderbottom_animate'] are in an absolute position, so when the new height is applied to them they would 'grow' towards the center of the parent div- if that makes sense. That's also why they're empty, I'll have other content in separate divs. I've achieved this through the :hover selector just on the two divs, but I want it to occur when the tab is selected.

Comment: Can you show this working with hover?

Comment: Also you can use less jQuery `var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5QLFU/ In using the :hover selector it's applied to the tabcontentcontainer class like `.tabcontentcontainer:hover .bordertop_animate` and `.tabcontentcontainer:hover .borderbottom_animate`, so you have to mouseover the image/content area to get the border height to change.

Comment: Ok. You only need to set transition once. Adding it to the :hover class doesn't do anything.

Comment: Alright, I've amended that in my css.

Comment: You should be able to do it by adding `.current .borderbottom_animate { height: 185px }` but I couldn't work out why it wasn't animating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase a div size on click with css alone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730294/increase-a-div-size-on-click-with-css-alone)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jquery solution to your problem, just in case you need it.
JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nPAhw/

html

```
<ul>
    <li id="tab1">Tab One</li>
    <li id="tab2">Tab Two</li>
</ul>

<div id="tabone">Tab one</div>
<div id="tabtwo">Tab Two</div>
```

css

```
#tabone{
    width:200px;
    height:38px;
    border:solid blue;
    margin:10px;
}
#tabtwo{
    width:200px;
    height:38px;
    border:solid black;
    margin:10px;
}
#tab1:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
#tab2:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

jquery / javascript

```
$('#tab1').click(function(){
    var h = $('#tabone').height();
    if(h < 185){    
        $('#tabone').animate({height:'185px'});
        $('#tabtwo').animate({height:'38px'});
    }
    else $('#tabone').animate({height:'38px'});
});

$('#tab2').click(function(){
    var h = $('#tabtwo').height();
    if(h < 185){    
        $('#tabtwo').animate({height:'185px'});
        $('#tabone').animate({height:'38px'});
    }
else $('#tabtwo').animate({height:'38px'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the [Jquery Animate method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

This method can perform animation effects on any numeric CSS property, like for example, height, which is what you want to achieve.

```
$( ".element-class" ).animate({
  height: "185px"
}, 500);
```

Comment: If you read the question OP is looking for a CSS3 solution, not jQuery animate.

Comment: I've seen the tag, but OP wrote that it was his firt time inquiring about jquery. He didn't specify that he wanted a full CSS3 solution.

Comment: Admittedly it is ambiguous, but he/she did include the tag CSS3 which  otherwise wouldn't be required, and talked about transition, and the jQuery is adding the class `.current` I'm sticking with my theory. :)

Comment: And it's perfectly fine by me. I believe both ways will achieve more or less the same result, althought i think i believe yours to be much more efficient :) I haven't really taken the time myself to test most of the CSS3 transition properties. I might look into that a bit more!

Comment: Yes you're right, both things will do a similar thing but where you can use CSS3 in place of animate you should. It's really easy to do the simple stuff. This, however, may take a little more time to set up: http://cssdeck.com/labs/dancing-robot-with-reflection (it's pure CSS)

Comment: I mostly use the greensock js library for animating stuff, but I will definitly take time to experiment with CSS3. That example is actualy pretty sweet tho