# React select div height when DOM is loaded

Tags: css, reactjs, window-load

I am having issues with react Plotly displaying correctly when a graph loaded in a hidden tab is selected. It seems this is a known issue where every tab but the default tab will not resize appropriately because it doesn't know the hidden graph's dimensions.

To get around this I would like to dynamically update the tab height to be equal to the height of the default tab. Something like this: [Change div height when tab is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844260/change-div-height-when-tab-is-selected).

The issue is, I am unable to select the tab height value on DOM load. I thought I could add a componentDidMount function with an evenlistener for window load like such:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: 0
        };
        this.handleLoad = this.handleLoad.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
    }

    handleLoad() {
        console.log("firstTab height: " + $('#firstTab').offsetHeight)
    }
```

This issue is, the console log is outputting firstTab height: undefined.

When i inspect the web page and put the command $('#firstTab').offsetHeight into the console I am able to come up with a height of 697 px.

I don't want to hardcode the tab pixel size. Can anyone guide me as to why I am failing to grab the element height on window load?

Answer (score 0):

Try using clientHeight property.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const height = document.getElementById('firstTab').clientHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using event listener, you can do something like this.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const height = this.firstTab.clientHeight;
    console.log(height) // => gives you height
}

render() {
    return (
      <div 
        id="firstTab"
        ref={ (firsTabElement) => { this.divElement = firstTabElement } }
      >
        Tab Content
      </div>
    )
  }
```

After the first render if you are not hiding or putting any condition to remove the firstTab from the DOM. It will be available to you in `componentDidMount` lifecycle.